# Jquery return selected name

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="MyId" name="Myname">
  <option value=1>Tom</option>
  <option value=12>Harold</option>e 
  <option value=32>Jenny</option>
</select>
```

With

```
$('select option:selected').each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    var text = $el.attr('text');
    alert(text);
 });
```

I can get Options text

But how to get Select tag name or id and selected option text? As following return `undefined:text`

```
    $('select option:selected').each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    var text = $el.attr('text');
    var name = $el.attr('name');
    alert(name + ":" + text);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.change()`

```
$('select').change(function() {
   var name = $(this).attr('name'); // get select tag name
   var id = $(this).attr('id'); // get select tag id
   var selectedOption = $(this).val(); // get selected option
   var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // get selected option text
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest()` or `parent()` to get the select whose id and name is required.

```
$('select option:selected').each(function () {    
    var select = $(this).parent('select');//the tag object
    alert($(this).closest('select').attr('id'));//id
    alert($(this).parent('select').attr('name'));//name
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This

$('select option:selected').each(function () {
  var $el = $(this);
  var text = $el.text();
  alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Its works for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Select Box</title>
        <script data-main="js/main" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('select[name="choice"]').change(function () {
                    var mySelect = $(this);
                    alert("selected " + mySelect.find('option:selected').text());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select  name="choice" >
            <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
            <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
            <option value='3'>Choice 3</option>
            <option value='4'>Choice 4</option>
            <option value='5'>Choice 5</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```